# Problems understand Routing in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I thought I had at least a bases for understanding routing in MVC after all the documentation I have read, only to fail at it when attempting to utilize it.

I have the following two routes declared in my Global.aspx

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I have a AdminController that I have a few methods, one that is "List" method that renders a list of products to a "List" view.

I thought I understood how RedirectToAction works, and I added an "Add" method (see below) that adds a new Product and returns a RedirectToAction which I understood would be the proper way to redirect to the List action on the same "AdminController"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Product product) {
    if (_prodRepo.Add(product)) {
        return RedirectToAction("List", "Admin");
    }
    return View("Add", product);
}
```

However, on the return of the "Add" it always attempts to route to the path `website.com/Account/Login/ReturnUrl=%2f`.

However, if I go to website.com/Admin it does render the list as I expect.  But when using the RedirectToAction as in the example above, it attempts to go to the `/Account/Login` (Controller/action).

It was my understanding that the RedirectToAction("List", "Admin") would route to the "List" method on the AdminController controller and that I was using it as expected.

Can someone please help me understand the reasoning behind this.  But also, could someone post some recommended articles for understanding the whole MVC routing including how the web.config works with routing.

Finally, it was also my understanding that route discovery by the framework is done in the order they are specified in your routes.MapRoute() declaration and stops at the first one that matches.  Therefore, if the first one is listed as Controller = "Admin", Action = "List", I would expect by convention that this is the correct route it would first match and return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes need to be different (the url parameter) since the first route with a matching url will be used.

This will therefore work for you:

```
routes.MapRoute("Admin", 
    "admin/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The defaults (third parameter in the method) are used if the parameters isn't found/specified in the uri.

As for your question regarding `/Account/Login/ReturnUrl=%2f`. The login redirections are handled by the `MembershipProvider` and not by the standard routing mechanism.

Comment: Thx.  I will mark this as an answer.  However, I am still not understanding why calling RedirectToAction("List", "Admin") does not resolve properly to the first listed route (that I have specified).  In addition, I know you mentioned the MembershipProvider, but how is that even coming into the mix?

Comment: `/Account/Login/ReturnUrl=%2f` is an url that Forms authentication uses if the user is not authenticated. The `RedirecToAction` should work when you have changed the route to what I suggested. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes.  It does work when I change it to your suggestion.  But I still don't understand why the first route {controller}/{action}/{id} of Controller = Admin, Action = List isn't selected when I call RedirectToAction("List", "Admin") which is specifying Exactly the same controller and action.

Comment: What do you mean not selected?

Comment: selected = as in that route from the route collection being "selected" as the route to be used.  {controller}/{action}/{id} is basically a copy of the MVC default which was put in place as a "Catch all", I only changed the controller and action defaults.  Therefore, If I call RedirectToAction("List", "Admin") I am explicitly stating "send to the List action on the AdminController" so when it is going through the defined routes in the order they were specified, it should come to my first route and say "I have a match" and direct to the "List" method on the "AdminController".  Right?

Comment: I don't understand what you expect? `RedirectToAction("List", "Admin")` should return exactly the same uri no matter if the first or second route matches it = the List action in Admin controller should be invoked. If you are referring to the `/Account/Login/ReturnUrl=%2f` uri it's because the membershipprovider is invoked before the MVC routing. If you don't want users to login, make sure that no authorization is made in your controller.